# win-ros configure.bat - no module named genmsg

Tags: ros, genmsg, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I followed the instructions from http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/win_ros(2f)Msvc(20)Build(20)Environment(202d20)Fuerte.html. All works fine but

configure.bat returns:

```
Found Boost components:
   date_time;thread
-- Using these generator languages from the installation: gencpp;genpy
C:/opt/ros/fuerte/x86/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em:33: error: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named genmsg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\em.py", line 3288, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\em.py", line 3286, in main
    invoke(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\em.py", line 3269, in invoke
```

This is the only error, other parts and even later nmake work.
Any hints what might be wrong?

Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35791/win-ros-configure.bat---no-module-named-genmsg/) by [jerry58](https://answers.ros.org/users/2552/jerry58/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you need a Python `genmsg` module installed somewhere.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0